# SFTP insert the list into sql database table using c sharp?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sftp

I get a list of attributes (filename, size and date) from a sftp client but I need to automatically insert that list into a SQL Server table. I have been able to connect to the database via Visual studio but now I have no idea how to insert that list into a database table.
please help!!!!

Here is my c sharp code that lists the attributes

```
public static void Main()
        {
            string host = @"sftp.com";
            string username = "myusername";
            string password = @"mypassword";
            string remoteDirectory = " ";

            using SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password);
            {
                try
                {
                    sftp.Connect();
                    var files = sftp.ListDirectory(".");
                    foreach (var file in files)

                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
                        SftpFile f = sftp.Get(file.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(f.Attributes.Size);
                        Console.WriteLine(f.Attributes.LastWriteTime);
                    }
                    sftp.Disconnect();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An exception has been caught " + e.ToString());
                }
```

Comment: Use ADO.NET: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/ado-net-using-sql-server/

Comment: Yeah I did look into inserting it into a table but how do I insert the list (which I already hv into a table?)...like in python I used                                                                         for f, s, d in zip(files,sizes,dates):
     cursor.execute('''
                    INSERT INTO dbo.name(FileName,FileSize,DateModified)
                    VALUES
                    (?,?,?)

                    ''', f, str(s), str(d))

Comment: You already have a for loop in your code.  The INSERT goes in there just like in Python.

Comment: I will try ....

Comment: didnt work @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: Then modify your question to include your attempt and more details of what “didn’t work” means.